# SQL query: How to only display certain rows when using aliasing?

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2014, row-number

I am trying to only display rows where rownum is between 0 and 24. This will be dynamic and the range will change depending on which page the user is on. For some reason the below query executes forever and never returns a result. If I delete this:

```
WHERE 
    rownum >= 0 AND rownum < 24 
ORDER BY 
    rownum;
```

The query then executes without issue.

How can I fix this query so that it will do what I want? and why is this one not working?:

```
WITH cs AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [RCA].[I_UID]) AS rownum, 
        [RCA].[I_UID], 
        [RCA].[I_TYPE_UID], 
        [RCA].[I_I_C], 
        [RCA].[L_D], 
        [RCA].[SOME_DATE], 
        [RCA].[ANOTHER_DATE], 
        [RCA].[ANOTHER_DATED], 
        [RCA].[L_ED_DATE], 
        [RCA].[L_ED_USER_UID], 
        [RCA].[PNT_UID], 
        [RCA].[FA_UID], 
        [RCA].[D_LE], 
        [RCA].[DIGITAL_A], 
        [RCA].[LOK], 
        [RCA].[KILP], 
        [RCA].[LKP], 
        [RCA].[BLT], 
        [RCA].[LAT], 
        [RCA].[JUT], 
        [RCA].[S_UID], 
        [S_A].[FAT_UID], 
        [S_A].[RD_UID], 
        [S_A].[S_CODE], 
        [S_A].[S_NAME], 
        [S_A].[S_TYPE_UID], 
        [S_A].[S_LENGTH], 
        [S_A].[CUP_LIMIT], 
        [S_A].[S_N_C], 
        [S_A].[S_N_D_JCT_TYPE_UID], 
        [S_A].[S_N_D_NAME], 
        [S_A].[ENC], 
        [S_A].[ENJT_UID], 
        [S_A].[ENT_NAME], 
        [S_A].[N_UID], 
        [S_A].[R_UID], 
        [S_A].[A_UID], 
        [S_A].[D_UID], 
        [S_A].[DI_UID], 
        [S_A].[SU_UID], 
        [S_A].[BS_T], 
        [S_A].[CLU_UID], 
        [S_A].[MH_UID], 
        [S_A].[EN_UID], 
        [S_A].[OWN_UID], 
        [S_A].[AG_UID], 
        [S_A].[DPT], 
        [S_A].[NPI], 
        [S_A].[R_W_C], 
        [S_A].[S_L_UID], 
        [S_A].[S_LF_T_CODE], 
        [S_A].[FT_I_UID], 
        [S_A].[F_O_UID], 
        [S_A].[DRN_C], 
        [S_A].[SUY_UID], 
        [S_A].[S_L_CS], 
        [S_A].[SUY], 
        [S_A].[MAX], 
        [S_A].[STRA_NO], 
        [S_A].[NOP], 
        [S_A].[CWXSP], 
        [S_A].[OFFCWXSP], 
        [S_A].[UK_M_HR_UID], 
        [S_A].[FWAY_M_HR_UID], 
        [S_A].[CYCLE_M_HR_UID], 
        [S_A].[UK_R_ROU_UID], 
        [S_A].[UK_R_DOT_CLUIFICATION_UID], 
        [S_A].[L_UID], 
        [S_A].[LOCAL_HR], 
        [S_A].[PG_DATE], 
        [S_A].[LCA_DIS_UID], 
        [S_A].[CWT], 
        [S_A].[LCA_OCC_L_UID], 
        [S_A].[SKL], 
        [S_A].[SKG] 
    FROM 
        RCA 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        S_A ON RCA.S_uid = S_A.S_uid
    WHERE 
        [RCA].[SOME_DATE] <= '02 december 2020'
        AND [RCA].[ANOTHER_DATE] >= '02 december 2020'
        AND [S_A].[SOME_DATE] <= '02 december 2020'
        AND [S_A].[ANOTHER_DATE] >= '02 december 2020'
) 
SELECT *
FROM cs
WHERE 
    rownum >= 0 AND rownum < 24 
ORDER BY 
    rownum;
```

**UPDATE:**

I have updated my query using OFFSET / FETCH for pagination. The query executes successfully only when I order by descending. When change it to `ORDER BY rownum ASC`, the query executes forever without returning any results. This is the query that works, however I require the results to be in ascending order:

```
SELECT 
        [RCA].[I_UID], 
        [RCA].[I_TYPE_UID], 
        [RCA].[I_I_C], 
        [RCA].[L_D], 
        [RCA].[SOME_DATE], 
        [RCA].[ANOTHER_DATE], 
        [RCA].[ANOTHER_DATED], 
        [RCA].[L_ED_DATE], 
        [RCA].[L_ED_USER_UID], 
        [RCA].[PNT_UID], 
        [RCA].[FA_UID], 
        [RCA].[D_LE], 
        [RCA].[DIGITAL_A], 
        [RCA].[LOK], 
        [RCA].[KILP], 
        [RCA].[LKP], 
        [RCA].[BLT], 
        [RCA].[LAT], 
        [RCA].[JUT], 
        [RCA].[S_UID], 
        [S_A].[FAT_UID], 
        [S_A].[RD_UID], 
        [S_A].[S_CODE], 
        [S_A].[S_NAME], 
        [S_A].[S_TYPE_UID], 
        [S_A].[S_LENGTH], 
        [S_A].[CUP_LIMIT], 
        [S_A].[S_N_C], 
        [S_A].[S_N_D_JCT_TYPE_UID], 
        [S_A].[S_N_D_NAME], 
        [S_A].[ENC], 
        [S_A].[ENJT_UID], 
        [S_A].[ENT_NAME], 
        [S_A].[N_UID], 
        [S_A].[R_UID], 
        [S_A].[A_UID], 
        [S_A].[D_UID], 
        [S_A].[DI_UID], 
        [S_A].[SU_UID], 
        [S_A].[BS_T], 
        [S_A].[CLU_UID], 
        [S_A].[MH_UID], 
        [S_A].[EN_UID], 
        [S_A].[OWN_UID], 
        [S_A].[AG_UID], 
        [S_A].[DPT], 
        [S_A].[NPI], 
        [S_A].[R_W_C], 
        [S_A].[S_L_UID], 
        [S_A].[S_LF_T_CODE], 
        [S_A].[FT_I_UID], 
        [S_A].[F_O_UID], 
        [S_A].[DRN_C], 
        [S_A].[SUY_UID], 
        [S_A].[S_L_CS], 
        [S_A].[SUY], 
        [S_A].[MAX], 
        [S_A].[STRA_NO], 
        [S_A].[NOP], 
        [S_A].[CWXSP], 
        [S_A].[OFFCWXSP], 
        [S_A].[UK_M_HR_UID], 
        [S_A].[FWAY_M_HR_UID], 
        [S_A].[CYCLE_M_HR_UID], 
        [S_A].[UK_R_ROU_UID], 
        [S_A].[UK_R_DOT_CLUIFICATION_UID], 
        [S_A].[L_UID], 
        [S_A].[LOCAL_HR], 
        [S_A].[PG_DATE], 
        [S_A].[LCA_DIS_UID], 
        [S_A].[CWT], 
        [S_A].[LCA_OCC_L_UID], 
        [S_A].[SKL], 
        [S_A].[SKG] 
    FROM 
        RCA 
    INNER JOIN 
        S_A ON RCA.S_uid = S_A.S_uid
    WHERE 
        [RCA].[SOME_DATE] <= '02 december 2020'
        AND [RCA].[ANOTHER_DATE] >= '02 december 2020'
        AND [S_A].[SOME_DATE] <= '02 december 2020'
        AND [S_A].[ANOTHER_DATE] >= '02 december 2020'

ORDER BY 
    [RCA].[I_UID] DESC

    OFFSET 0 ROWS
    FETCH FIRST 24 ROWS ONLY;
```

**Final working solution:**

```
;WITH cs AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        t.S_UID,
        t.I_UID,
        t.[I_TYPE_UID], 
        t.[I_I_C], 
        t.[L_D], 
        t.[SOME_DATE], 
        t.[ANOTHER_DATE], 
        t.[ANOTHER_DATED], 
        t.[L_ED_DATE], 
        t.[L_ED_USER_UID], 
        t.[PNT_UID], 
        t.[FA_UID], 
        t.[D_LE], 
        t.[DIGITAL_A], 
        t.[LOK], 
        t.[KILP], 
        t.[LKP], 
        t.[BLT], 
        t.[LAT], 
        t.[JUT], 
        S_A.[FAT_UID], 
        S_A.[RD_UID], 
        S_A.[S_CODE], 
        S_A.[S_NAME], 
        S_A.[S_TYPE_UID], 
        S_A.[S_LENGTH], 
        S_A.[CUP_LIMIT], 
        S_A.[S_N_C], 
        S_A.[S_N_D_JCT_TYPE_UID], 
        S_A.[S_N_D_NAME], 
        S_A.[ENC], 
        S_A.[ENJT_UID], 
        S_A.[ENT_NAME], 
        S_A.[N_UID], 
        S_A.[R_UID], 
        S_A.[A_UID], 
        S_A.[D_UID], 
        S_A.[DI_UID], 
        S_A.[SU_UID], 
        S_A.[BS_T], 
        S_A.[CLU_UID], 
        S_A.[MH_UID], 
        S_A.[EN_UID], 
        S_A.[OWN_UID], 
        S_A.[AG_UID], 
        S_A.[DPT], 
        S_A.[NPI], 
        S_A.[R_W_C], 
        S_A.[S_L_UID], 
        S_A.[S_LF_T_CODE], 
        S_A.[FT_I_UID], 
        S_A.[F_O_UID], 
        S_A.[DRN_C], 
        S_A.[SUY_UID], 
        S_A.[S_L_CS], 
        S_A.[SUY], 
        S_A.[MAX], 
        S_A.[STRA_NO], 
        S_A.[NOP], 
        S_A.[CWXSP], 
        S_A.[OFFCWXSP], 
        S_A.[UK_M_HR_UID], 
        S_A.[FWAY_M_HR_UID], 
        S_A.[CYCLE_M_HR_UID], 
        S_A.[UK_R_ROU_UID], 
        S_A.[UK_R_DOT_CLUIFICATION_UID], 
        S_A.[L_UID], 
        S_A.[LOCAL_HR], 
        S_A.[PG_DATE], 
        S_A.[LCA_DIS_UID], 
        S_A.[CWT], 
        S_A.[LCA_OCC_L_UID], 
        S_A.[SKL], 
        S_A.[SKG] 
       
    FROM 
        RCA AS t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        S_A ON t.S_UID = S_A.S_UID
    
    WHERE 
        t.[SOME_DATE] <= '02 december 2020'
        AND t.[ANOTHER_DATE] >= '02 december 2020'

    ORDER BY t.[I_UID]
        OFFSET 24 * 0 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 24 ROWS ONLY
) 

SELECT *
FROM cs
ORDER BY 
cs.I_UID
```

Comment: This works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3d4d734261b124257bc356cb0492c9b7

Comment: Odd, it's the same. Any idea what could cause the above not to work? the query works if I delete the WHERE part of the final select

Comment: How much data do you have ? You do not say that it does not work, you explain that it takes too much time ?

Comment: just over 72 thousand lines. If I delete the WHERE part of the statement it takes approximately 7 to 11 seconds to execute. with the query as it is with the WHERE, it doesn't error, it just executes forever (I've left it for 30 mins and it was still executing)

Comment: Often `OFFSET`/`FETCH` is used for pagination.

Comment: @GordonLinoff using offset / fetch only executes successfully if I use `ORDER BY DESC` but not when I use `ORDER BY ASC` which is what is required.

Comment: @NickyLarson . . . That seems surprising.  I am not aware of limitations based on the ordering of the sort -- performance might differ due to different execution plans though.

Answer (score 1):

Would TOP be something you need:

```
SELECT  top 3 t.id
         , t.age
         , t.name
         , t.surname
         , t2.workplace
FROM test t
left join test2 t2 on t.id = t2.id
```

Here is a demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=d149447573f72378d18001c816d5909d)

And how about this:

```
SELECT   t.id
         , t.age
         , t.name
         , t.surname
         , t2.workplace
FROM test t
left join test2 t2 on t.id = t2.id
ORDER BY t.id
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0298762a7c40bdc115661701a9392246)

Comment: Thanks but the user needs to be able to use ROW_NUMBER() to give a number to each row and TOP will only ever return the top records, so when the user changes page, it will not work

Comment: Hi @NickyLarson I have updated my answer... Maybe this will be ok...

Comment: that should also work in theory but for some reason it only works if I run that query using `ORDER BY t.id DESC`. It doesn't work using `ORDER BY t.id ASC`

Comment: Hi @NickyLarson What does that mean -- It doesn't work using ORDER BY t.id ASC ? Can you explain little bit more ?

Comment: I have updated my post to show exactly what I mean. The updated query I have posted above works, but the query executes forever without returning any results if I change it to: `ORDER BY rownum ASC`, which is what is required.

Comment: Hi @NickyLarson but you have replaced the rownum with fetch and offset what do you need rownum now ? Remove it and order by id.

Comment: yes exactly the same problem though, it still only works with DESC (see updated post).

Comment: You do not have every id ? hmmmm  ok. I understand but I can not reproduce...

Comment: Hi @NickyLarson can you order by SECTION_UID ?

Comment: I just tried it. order by SECTION_UID ascending works. I don't understand why ordering by ITEM_UID or rownum wouldn't though. Maybe because it has to process over 1.6 million ITEM_UIDs to get the required range when using ascending?

Comment: Hi @NickyLarson I believe it is because null values...not sure. Does order by SECTION_UID works for you? Is it a solution you can use ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I need to order by ITEM_UID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225525/discussion-between-vboka-and-nickylarson).

Comment: I have finally come up with a working solution. If you want to incorporate my working query (updated in original post) into your solution, I will accept it as the correct answer. Thank you for all your help

Comment: Hi @NickyLarson You are welcome, happy to help. Happy to hear that you have found the solution.